# Selection not visible when using graphite mode from Autodesk.NPR in viewer v7.51

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Upgraded the viewer from version v6.5 to v7.51.

When we turn on the graphite mode from the Autodesk.NPR extension, the selection is no longer visible. Doing some testing with setting the brightness to 0.5 I can see that the issue appears to be that the selection colour is set to white.

I tried setting the selection colour back to the default after we initialised the extension but it has had no affect.

```
myViewer.setBackgroundColor(255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255);
var ext=myViewer.getExtension('Autodesk.NPR');
ext.setParameter("style", "graphite");
ext.setParameter("brightness", 1.0);
myViewer.setSelectionColor(new THREE.Color(0.4, 0.6, 1));
```

This all worked fine before the upgrade from v6.5 to v7.51.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried the `Autodesk.NPR` extension in v7.*:

### No selection

[image: v7-npr-noselection]

### With selection color (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)

[image: v7-npr-whiteselection]

### With selection color (0.3, 0.6, 0.9)

[image: v7-npr-blueselection]

The white selection does show up, but of course in the graphite style it is barely noticeable. I would consider this the expected behavior. Or how was the appearance different in v6.5?

EDIT: here's the code I used to enable the NPR extension and set the blue selection color:

```js
viewer.setBackgroundColor(255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255);
const ext = await viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.NPR');
ext.setParameter('style', 'graphite');
ext.setParameter('brightness', 1.0);
viewer.setSelectionColor(new THREE.Color(0.3, 0.6, 0.9));
```

Comment: Hey Petr,

When I set selection colour using the code I've shown above it has no affect. Can you add the code you used to change the selection colour?

I've tried both myViewer.setSelectionColor(new THREE.color(0.3,0.6,0.9) and myViewer.impl.setSelectionColor(new THREE.color(0.3,0.6,0.9) with no luck.

Comment: I've updated my answer, including the code snippet I use to enable the NPR mode and set the blue selection color. I'm using viewer v7.*. Here's the complete code: https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-simple-viewer-nodejs/tree/sample/npr-selection-color.